# wx controls using a different background colour than they specify

Tags: python, wxpython

If I run

```
panel.SetBackgroundColour(panel.GetBackgroundColour())
```

on a wxPython panel, the colour changes!
What's happening here? And how do I get the real colour being used?

Comment: What OS and wx version? I can't replicate this on Windows 7, wx 2.9.3.1, Python 2.6.6.

Comment: Thanks for trying! Using Fedora and wx 2.8.12.0 (gtk2-unicode) under python 2.7.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your current GTK theme uses a texture for the background then it probably defines an approximate match for the background color, which is what you get from GetBackgroundColour.  By passing that to the setter you're telling the window to use that color instead of the texture.

Another possibility is if the theme alters the default color in certain contexts, such as what Windows will do if the panel is a page in a notebook.  By setting the color to something else (even if it's the default) then you are overriding the theme and it will not do whatever it is doing to the windows color.

Comment: Notebooks! The controls I tested with _were_ on a notebook so that may be the answer. Using Fedora though, so it might not be the same thing :)

Comment: Well... Found the same behaviour on normal panels now. No gradients or fancy see through effects enabled :(